# correct tense of verb after 'what if'

Tags: grammaticality, tenses

I'm not sure about whether I should say

> what if fracture leads to a catastrophe?

or

> what if fracture led to a catastrophe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question "What if fracture leads to a catastrophe?" clearly refers to the present time, and is short for:

- What **will happen** if fracture leads to a catastrophe?" (This is what we know as a conditional type I: if something happens, something else will o may happen.)

The question "What if fracture led to a catastrophe?" can be set in the past OR in the present time. Compare:

- The union leaders **had decided** to fracture their organization, but what if fracture **led** to a catastrophe? (This means that, at that PAST time, the union leaders wondered, after deciding to fracture the union, what WOULD/COULD happen if fracture actually LED to a catastrophe.)
- The union leaders **are discussing** the possibility of fracturing their organization, but what if fracture **led** to a catastrophe? (This is a conditional type II, which means: What WOULD/COULD happen in the FUTURE in the unlikely event that fracture LED to a catastrophe -- here, "led" is in the past tense but expresses a hypothetical future time.)

Note: I'm attaching a couple of dictionary references to dispel any doubts as to the grammaticality of "what if" + past tense. The references (the examples in the case of Longman, the definition in the case of MWU) also show that "what if" are conditional sentences in which the result is ellided:

[image: Longman]

[image: MWU]

Comment: This strikes me as wrong in its entirety. First of all, the sentence is a hypothetical interrogative. It isn’t a conditional. *What if* doesn’t introduce a protasis. You can’t say, “What if fracture leads to a catastrophe, then we’ll be unhappy.” While *leads* is present tense as a verb form, as a hypothetical, its relationship with present time is less clear. The simple past *led* strikes me as borderline ungrammatical. If the action is completed, then there’s no need to wonder whether it would happen. It either has or it hasn’t. [con't]->

Comment: <-[con't]We express past hypotheticals in the past perfect: *What if fracture **had led** to catastrophe?* I can’t even get this locution to work with a backshift in reported speech. Suppose the union leader asks, “What if fracture leads to catastrophe?” Does  it seem natural to transpose this into indirect speech with *The union leaded asked what if fracture **led** to catastrophe*? The present continuous *are discussing* seems particularly inapt with a possibility in the past. Wouldn’t it be *what if fracture leads*? [con't]->

Comment: <-[con't] I suppose past tense *discussed* and past tense *led* would work for past narrative, but it still sounds awkward tome. In any case, a type II conditional requires a modal verb in the main clause.

Comment: This may be a semantic elision, but that requires rephrasing the sentence with a different grammatical structure. There's no syntactic elision in the sense of dropping the relative conjunction in a reduced relative clause, an operation that does not change the structure. Note that your MW example, *What if we moved the sofa?* is past tense but does not refer to past time, which makes your answer all the more confusing to me. Sorry, I don't know what *GB* is.

Comment: @deadrat In "what if" clauses, the result is ellided: *What (will/would happen) if something (else) happens/happened?* You can find many examples at GB. If you want to report any *what if* question, you will need to make the result clause explicit: *The union leaders wondered what would happen if fracture led to catastrophe.* I am adding a couple of dictionary references for you to see that "what if" clauses can work with the past tense

Comment: @deadrat GB is Google Books

Comment: *GB* Of course. Brain freeze.

Comment: @deadrat I see nothing wrong with: *As tenants they had agreed to keep the furniture as it was, but what if they moved the sofa nearer the TV? Would the landlord go mad? It wouldn't make a world of difference.*

Comment: Sorry, sounds odd to me, but maybe that's just me. They had agreed (past perfect), so there's some past time before which the agreement is made. But the past time of the conditional is free grammatically but not chronologically. If they're still contemplating moving the sofa, I'd say "if they move*; if this is past narrative and they've all moved out by now, I'd say "if they had moved*.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question in a very straight forward way:

Sentence 1 is in a present context and Sentence 2 is in the past relative to the present.

If you are discussing an event at the current moment which happened in the past; sentence 2 is correct.

Otherwise, a current discussion questioning future outcomes relative to the moment at which you write would refer to sentence 1.

I hope it answered your question.

Comment: "What if fracture led to catastrophe" can refer to the past or to an improbable present context, in line with conditionals type II: What **would happen** if fracture led to catastrophe?

Comment: So the answer is not complete?

Comment: @aaragon No, I find it to be incomplete.